# Is the tdm-gcc project still active?

Tags: mingw, codeblocks, tdm-gcc

Last update of the TDM-GCC distribution from the [website](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) dates back to July 2015. 
The version of the bundled GCC compiler is 5.1.0 . 
Code::Blocks IDE can use much newer versions of both 32 and 64 bits.

Comment: Since he hasn't even commented on any bug reports in the last 1.5 years, I guess not.

Comment: From this ticket status, it looks like John(the author of TDM GCC) has some activity in 2017-12, see  here: [TDM-GCC MinGW Compiler / Bugs / #329 ”D:run: No such file or directory“ error while debugging source file on root directory](https://sourceforge.net/p/tdm-gcc/bugs/329/)